# Help with understanding a dialogue

Tags: listening

There is this [scene](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/f7d57a50-e883-459e-abe8-f9e218fa2eae) in the movie "Good Will Hunting" that says:

> I had the router do all the bodywork

All the other subtitles I've found have written the same thing But it doesn't make sense..There is no  "router" tool in the body work and it doesn't match with the context.

I think "Morgan" guy in the movie is saying something else and all subtitles are wrong.I have guesses but I'm not sure.
How do you hear that sentence?

Comment: I think you mean "understanding" not "underasting". It would also help if you described what happens in the scene for people who don't like to click random links.

Comment: But his friends respond him with like:
"Chucky : Guy's been up my ass for two years about a job. I had to let him help with the car.". 
"Billy :  Yeah, I have a fuckin' job, too, brother." 
I think what Morgan said was "I had order to do all the bodywork"

Comment: FWIW, I hear, "I had the roader do all the body work." "Roader" isn't a common English word, and none of the definitions I found for it match, but that's the sounds I hear. It might mean something in Boston English.

Comment: It's just another couple of guesses.  It is very slurred.  One guess is "rotor" which is plausibly slang for a rotating buffer.  Another guess is "I had the role to do all the bodywork". That makes the response make sense "I have a fucking job too" (don't complain about doing this long boring task, because you're unemployed and I'm not)

Comment: It's "role" surely?

Comment: @JamesK my guess was "i had the order to do all the body work" because "Chucky" says later that he gave Morgan that job but "role" also makes more sense because  they were talking about their role in preparing that car as a present gift. Is there any chance what he said was "I had the order"?

Comment: @StuartF sorry for inconvenience..here is YouTube link: https://youtu.be/DI_HT98jaf0?t=83

Comment: But  that's not what Morgan says.  He doesn't say "Fuck you",   He says "I ........  bodywork"  where "......." sounds like "hadarota"  There's no mention of Bondo or anything that sounds like it.#

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ELL is not a transcription service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speech is slurred and not fully intelligible.

script shows that the scripted line was

> I did the body work. Whose fuckin' router you think sanded out all that Bondo

"Router" is here being used as generic term for a power tool, similar to a sander.

Either the actor misspoke, or the script was changed on set.  There are significant deviations of the words spoken by the actors from the script throughout.

Listening to the context as much as the words themselves suggests that the actual line as spoken is either

> I had the router do all the bodywork.

That is nonsense, and would be a mistake on the part of the actor. Or possibly

> I had the role to do all the bodywork.

This makes the response make sense, but the use of "role" is slightly odd.

It is probably best to decide not to worry too much about this one throwaway line. It isn't spoken clearly and it may be a simple mistake by the actor.

Comment: But the script is clearly not followed by the actors.  Much of this scene is either improvised or has been re-written prior to shooting.

Comment: I hear him say, "I had the router **to** do all the bodywork", which is pretty sensible, and expresses the same idea as the script (I did the work because I already had the router that was needed).

Comment: But it doesn't explain Chuckie's response.  (which is also not scripted)

Comment: Maybe not.  I can make some sense of it, but I could be imagining it, since there's a lot of subtext.  I see it like this - CHUCKIE: "Bill and I got the parts and Morgan contributed a tiny amount of money, because he's a loser who doesn't work" MORGAN: "[objecting] I did more than that; I did the body work, because I already had the router"  BILL: "And you did a bad job with it" CHUCKIE: "He did a bad job and we knew he would, but Morgan's always bugging me to give him a job, so I had to let him help"